# How do I get the size of a file(BFILE) in oracle g11 directly from a directory in my pc?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I was trying to get the size of a file from my desktop in Oracle SQL Developer, I'm working with a "BFILE" field.

[image]

And this is the query that I'm using

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  v_bfile BFILE;
begin
  select valor into v_bfile from TABLA_BFILE where id = 4;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El archivo ocupa: '||DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_bfile)||' bytes.');
end;
```

And I'm getting the next error

```
ORA-06512: en "SYS.DBMS_LOB", línea 787
ORA-06512: en línea 5
22285. 00000 -  "non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you running the Oracle database on your local machine too?  An anonymous block runs on the database server so it can only access files stored on the database server.  How did `tableA_BFile` get populated?  Are you sure that the `bfile` was created the way you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is running on my local machine. I was following an example from this sql "insert into TABLA_BFILE values (4, BFILENAME('C:\USERS\ROBERTO\DESKTOP\', 'oracle.jpg'));", but I'm not sure if the file is going to the directory. Do you have any idea about how can I store a file from sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine.
The issue was with the population of the table.
The directory should not be a path but a DIRECTORY object.

```
create directory DESKTOP as 'C:\Users\Roberto\Desktop';
Insert into TABLA_BFILE (ID,valor) values (1,BFILENAME('DESKTOP','oracle.jpg'));
```

Comment: I was missing the directory, once I wrote down that, it worked! Thank you! :D